# How to check resource creation success in Azure Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I'm creating several resources in Azure using python SDK but i'm confused how to check whether the resource is successfully created or not ?

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-core/azure.core.polling.lropoller?view=azure-python#methods) says the poller has multiple methods - done(), wait(), result() etc to check if status of the resource but what is the safe way to create a resource ?

ex:

```
try:
    resource = client.virual_machines.begin_create_or_update(...)
    
    # option 1
    count = 1
    while not resource.done(): #done() returns true or false
        time.sleep(timeout)
        if count > 10:
            raise
        count += 1
    
    # option 2
    response = resource.result() # result() returns the object of the corresponding resource
    if not isinstance(response, VirtualMachine):
        raise
        
    
    # option 3
    resource.wait(timeout)
    # check the status() function and based on the status of
    # ('inprogress', 'done', 'provisioning', 'succedded')
    # add a manual check and raise exception

except Exception as e:
```

what is the best option/way to handle/check resource creation ?
or is there any way to handle it properly ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score -2):

After provisioning the resource like you said we will be using poller along with the respective method in order to check the status/result of the resource being created or not.

For Provisioning the resources and to check the status you can check this [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-example-virtual-machines?tabs=cmd#3-write-code-to-provision-a-virtual-machine).

Comment: I have already checked this example, there they are creating a resource and are just taking the POLLER.result() value but not checking on the success/failure of operation. What i need is an efficient way to check on the operations success